# Case status is not changing for one value of Category

Tags: configuration

case-status doesn't change from "New" to "In Progress" even after a first response is sent out from SFDC. 
If I send an email using Send Email button or change any other field value, Case status is changing from New to In Progress. But I have on picklist called Category. In that picklist value for one value case status is not changing after a first response is sent out from SFDC.

Ex: IF Category value is "programme" Case status is not changing for any response.
    IF Category value is other than "Programme" Case status is changing for any response.

I've gone through all classes and workflows. But I couldn't find any result.

Is that a standard functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change Case status based on email sends/receives, you have to create your own workflow.  See this [help page article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000181633&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1).

> To create workflow rules that updates case object fields based on
>   Email Messages sent or received, it would require you to create
>   workflow rules using the object "email message".

This means there some Process Builder or workflow or Apex trigger that is driving your process, so you'll have to check it all again since that's the only place it can be.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the valuable information. I will need to update case object not only when an email sent or received. what even action happen after creating record. Like when other field update also status should change.

Comment: Then you will need to modify the existing workflow or process that is making the changes you described in your post.